# In android what should I use to send a http delete request (with parameters)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, http-delete

I've been using `HttpURLConnection` and it's been working so far, and it handles cookies with two lines but now I need to call a http delete request and it needs parameters and the server gets them form the body.

Apparently you can't send a delete method with a body, so I'm not sure if there's a workaround or if I have to abandon `HttpURLConnection` and use something else for the whole app.

Is there a way to use something else for delete while keeping `httpURLConnection` for the rest of the app, and what's the recommended one. And is it possible to also give it the session made in still giving it the session made in cookiemanager?

Comment: Android sdk Version 9.

Comment: Oracle Jdeveloper if that's what you mean